# storing email-validation regex string in JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json, email-validation

I have a regex string for validating email addresses, and I'd like to send it down to my application over json.  I get an error from [dojo/Json](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/json.html) saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

So I took my JSON file and dropped it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and got this slightly more specific error:

```
Parse error on line 3:
... {        "regex": "^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Here's my json file contents:

```
{
"Email Address": {
    "regex": "^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"
    }
}
```

Json.org doesn't seem to say anything about escaping regex characters...and the string itself is escaped properly because I can set a variable to that regex string in a js console.

Anyone know what I can do to get this to work?

Comment: You sure it's the same after you set it to a variable in the console?  Looks like you need to double escape your backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesnt work because your using " within the strings.

One work around would be to replace every " with something like /'\ then what you parse it again replace every /'\ with " and that will work.

Will look in to a better way but hopefuly this helps in the mean time.

UPDATE:

Every base 64 encode it then decode it: similar to http://decodebase64.com/

And save the base 64 encode regex when your doing stringify and then when you parse decode the the base 64 and store it back..

So basicly

-when wanting to stringify
-base64 encode regex
-Overwrite normal regex with base 64
-Stringify json

-when wanting to parse JSON
- Parse it in
- Get base 64 reg ex
- Decode it
- Replace it

Comment: I just realized that since it worked in the console, I could json encode it from the console.
    "^(([^<>()[].,;:s@\"]+(.[^<>()[].,;:s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$" 
Thats the fixed string.  Base64 is a good idea as well, but it takes a lot more processing time to go into and out of base64 so I was trying to avoid that.